# Why isn't my counter going up after each loop through the code?

Tags: java

This program should check the string you input for vowels and then output the amount of vowels. However, when I run the program, the counter displays 0. There are no errors being displayed by Eclipse.

I would expect that if I type in `hello` then it would display `2`, but it always displays `0`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Lab5 {
  public static boolean isVowel(char x) {
    if (x == 'A' || x == 'E' || x == 'I' || x == 'O' || x == 'U') {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String seq;
    boolean vowel;
    int counter = 0;
    seq = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a sequence of characters: ");
    seq.toUpperCase();
    for (int i=0; i<seq.length(); i++) {
        vowel = isVowel(seq.charAt(i));
        if (vowel == true) {
            counter++;
        }   
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number of vowels in your sequence of characters is : " + counter);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're starting to attract close votes for the question not being clear enough on desired behaviour. I've edited to clarify. The close-vote brigade is quite hard to satisfy sometimes.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight This doesn't seem like a duplicate *question* to me. It might have the same *answer* as another question does, but that's a different matter. The question "What is 2+2?" is not a duplicate of "What is 3+1?".

Comment: @chiastic-security - *'The question "What is 2+2?" is not a duplicate of "What is 3+"'*.  Literally, you are correct.  But one purpose of "close as duplicate" is to avoid StackOverflow being cluttered up with zillions of Q&A's that are *almost* the same, even if they are not literal duplicates.  And if you read the linked Q&A, it does give the solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: @StephenC I really meant that the questions are totally different, even if the answers are the same. I realise that where the *questions* are almost the same then it is enough to warrant closure, but I don't think that's true here.

Comment: @chiastic-security - The code is different.  The root problem is the same.  That is sufficient to warrant closure, IMO.  If you don't like it, take this to the SO "meta" site.  (But I don't fancy your chances of convincing people.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `seq.toUpperCase()` doesn't do what you think it does. It *returns a copy* of the `String`, converted to upper case, but it doesn't alter the original. (A `String` is immutable in Java, so it can't alter it.)

Try changing that line to

```
seq = seq.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: or just check for lower case vowels in the function..

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable in Java, so you can't modify them in place. When you call `toUpperCase()` on a string, it will return a copy of that string with all the characters changed to their upper-case equivalent, but the original string is left unchanged.

This means that you have to assign the result of calling `toUpperCase` to your variable again. So, instead of

```
seq.toUpperCase();
```

Do

```
seq = seq.toUpperCase();
```